# DotNet Core for Mac not running

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

Hello stack overflow community!
I'm facing some issues some days and didn't found any solution so far making some web researching.

I made a Visual Studio update recently on my Mac and my projects aren't running anymore. I can build, work as usual but when i try to run, it's getting the following error:

```
dotnet run
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'System.Native' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libSystem.Native, 1): image not found
at Interop.Sys.Dup(SafeFileHandle oldfd)
at System.ConsolePal.<>c.<OpenStandardOutput>b__9_0()
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandleHelper.Open(Func`1 fdFunc)
at System.ConsolePal.OpenStandardOutput()
at System.Console.<>c.<get_Out>b__26_0()
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
at System.Console.get_Out()
at System.Console.WriteLine(String value)
at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

ps: Even with a single new project and just running it.

It seems the compiler is not finding the SDK DLLs to run, or something like that.

Does someone has passed that before?

when i run dotnet --list-runtimes

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.23 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.23 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Thanks...

Comment: Which framework are you targeting, and is that runtime installed (`dotnet --list-runtimes`)?

Comment: Hi @gunr2171 i set the command result inside main description...

Comment: It was a terrible edit and terrible job of reviewers. Rolled back just for the priciple

Comment: Throw Mac away. Buy another pc & Install windows xD

Answer (score 1):

I finally understand what's going on! I just set the freshest Target Framework and it worked fine!

[image: screenshot]